# Web API for getting Apple Watch data [Health Data]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

Is there an open API to get the data from Apple watch and display it on Web App? I just need some basic data from the Apple Watch to be displayed on the web portal.

Can we only access Apple Watch data by creating an IOS app?

Comment: HealthKit data is only available from an iOS app. There is no web service that exposes this data because it is not stored on the web. It is highly sensitive, private data and is stored only on the user's device.  You would need to create an iOS app that obtains the user's permission to upload selected health data to your own web server

Comment: No need to create any app to do that, you have the builtin shortcuts app which lets you access your health data and also make api requests.